# Advise on mongodb sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I read mongodb sharding guide, but I am not sure what kind of shard key suits my application. Any suggestions are welcome.

My application is a huge database of network events. Each document has a time filed and a couple of network related values like IP address and port number. I have the insert rate of 100-1000 items per seconds. In my experience with a single mongod, one single shard has no problem with this insert rate.

But I extensively use aggregation framework on huge amount of data. All the aggregations has a time limit--i.e. mostly the recent month or the recent week. I tested the aggregations on one singe mongod and a query with response time of 5 minutes while the insertion is off could take as long as two hours if the 200 insert per seconds is activated.

Can I improve mongodb aggregation query response time by sharding?

If yes, I think I have to use time as the shard key, because in my application, every query has to be run on a time limit (e.g. Top IP addresses in the recent month) and if we can separate the shard that inserting is take place and the shard that the query is working the mongodb could work much faster.

But the documenation says

"If the shard key is a linearly increasing field, such as time, then all requests for a given time range will map to the same chunk, and thus the same shard. In this situation, a small set of shards may receive the majority of requests and the system would not scale very  well."

So what shall I do?

Comment: You might want to investigate using a hashed shard key, for example sharding on a hash of the time filed key. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#sharding-hashed-sharding says "Hashed keys work well with fields that increase monotonically like ObjectId values or timestamps." I offer this as a comment because I've never tried it and have no idea what effect it will actually have on your report's performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I improve mongodb aggregation query response time by sharding?

Yes.

If you shard your database on different machines this will provide parallel computing power on aggregation functions. The important thing is here the distribution of the data in your shards. It should be uniform distributed.

If you choose your shard key as a monotonicly increasing(or decreasing) field of the document-like time- and use hashed sharding, this will provide uniform distribution over the cluster.